# How do you save an image in Firefox using the keyboard?

Tags: firefox, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

Sometimes I need to use a (normally Windows) computer without mouse control. What is the fastest way to save an image to the disk in Firefox under these conditions?

An out-of-the-box solution is preferred since one with an addon would require installing it on every new system.

Comment: Out of curiosity... I don't mean to insult you, but why would you seek to do something as complicated as that with only the keyboard while you could simply plug in a mouse and do it all in two or three clicks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way would be:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>: Go to the `Page info`; (second button is capital `i` - `I`)
2. <kbd>→</kbd>: Switch to the `Media` tab.
3. <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Switch to the list of multimedia content.
4. Select image you want and then, using <kbd>Tab</kbd> go to the `Save as`.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In Windows:

<kbd>F7</kbd>: Go to caret mode

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑,↓,←,→</kbd>: Highlight the image

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>e</kbd>: View selection source

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑,↓,←,→</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> : Select & copy the image link (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>,<kbd>L</kbd> if the image is clickable)

<kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Return</kbd>: Open image (may require editing of existing URL)

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>: Open Save Dialog.

This is really crummy & hopefully there is a faster way